# How do I display database rows on multiple pages with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a database with a table having a big number of rows. I am fetching the data in this table and displaying it in an HTML table on a web page.

My requirement is to display 20 records initially and then when the user clicks a button labelled `Next`, I show the next 20 records and so on...

So I have initially fetched first 20 rows from the table in my PHP (server-side), and then assigned a JS function to the `onclick` attribute of the `button` labelled `Next`. Inside this JS function, I use an AJAX call which brings me the next 20 rows. Then within this JS function, I replace the HTML rows with these new rows.

I need something like this:

[image]

**The question is that are there any plugins available which can implement that functionality for me?** If a plugin is available, implementing it manually wouldn't make sense because being a rookie, I can't develop it better than the developers of that plugin.

Comment: You can use [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Comment: you may use any jquery plugin for pagination , jqgrid is my favourite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

This is called **pagination** - a quick search for "ajax pagination mysql php" or similar brings up a [wide range of options](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=ajax%20mysql%20pagination). I can't recommend any particular one as your question is too broad; I can only reasonably go as far as a definition.

Internally they use the [MySQL LIMIT keyword](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp) which may help give further things to search for or experiment with depending on your actual use case.

Comment: Thank you Luke Briggs. I did Not know that it's called pagination. So thank you. Besides, I think now that I know what it is called, I can easily google for plugins. So it does answer the question I guess. @icecub

Comment: @icecub Yeah I also feel that although this answer did help me out, they can include the name of a plugin or something like that, and that will answer the question perfectly (I believe)

Comment: @icecub But I am not asking for the Best plugin. I am rather asking if plugins exist for that purpose. That is a simple yes or no. Isn't it?

Comment: @icecub You could encourage me a bit as well :s Anyways I will delete my question in a few minutes, as SO people are expected to close it anyway (so I should at least beat them to the punch)